# how to add extra components to the new simple_form 2.0.0.rc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, simple-form

I am trying to add an extra component called Description, which is just a div with some text, before the INPUT component in a wrapper called :with_descripiton

I have in my initializer:

```
config.wrappers :with_description do |b|
  b.use :placeholder
  b.use :html5
  b.use :description
  b.use :input
  b.use :hint
  b.use :error
end
```

in my #app/inputs/description_component.rb

```
  module SimpleForm 
    module Components 
      module Description
        def description
          "Hello There!!!"
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

and finally in my view

```
   <%= f.input :due_at, :wrapper => :with_description %>
```

and I get the error

```
undefined method `description' for #<SimpleForm::Inputs::StringInput:0x007fb7a5ca95e0>
```

anyone has dealt with the new simple form who might have an idea what goes wrong here?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3):

Are you describing the correct code in the files? It looks like what you're referring to as your app/inputs file is actually your lib/simple_form file. If that's the case, and everything else is in good order, it looks like the part where your module gets included in Inputs::Base is missing:

```
module SimpleForm 
  module Components 
    module Description
      def description
        "Hello There!!!"
      end
    end
  end
  module Inputs 
    class Base 
      include SimpleForm::Components::Description
    end 
  end 
end
```

Comment: Hi Tom, for the last version of SimpleForm, I did put the file in lib/ directory, which worked. But it no longer works for some reason. --- I tried adding the second part about the module Inputs ... end but to no avail; doesn't work even if I put the file back in lib with or without the module Input...end lines.

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up custom inputs and custom components. According to their github readme it looks like it's all handled by the initializer. No app/inputs, no lib/simple_form, just define your wrapper in config/initializers/simple_form. Check their wiki.

Comment: See also https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Adding-custom-components, where it suggests the shorter `SimpleForm::Inputs::Base.send(:include, SimpleForm::Components::Numbers)`